# Azure - Sort order of List operation on blob container

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, collation

What is the sort order of a list operation on a blob container? Is it like Azure Table Storage, where it is alphabetic?

Comment: It seems empirical evidence points to alphabetic, but without a guarantee in the specs I won't code against that assumption. Does one exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the last line of "List Blobs" in MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135734.aspx

> Blobs are listed in alphabetical order in the response body.

---

As an aside, in one of the PDC deep dive talks, the storage team talked about the fact that blobs are keyed on a combination of the container name and blob path, so this is what determines the list order - and it also determines "hot spots" if you are hitting blob storage for lots of similarly named files.

Answer (score 2):

Given that blobs supports an equivalent of the continuation tokens used by table storage ([Marker/NextMarker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135734.aspx)) the order that blobs are returned in would have to be fixed.  While it's not explicitly mentioned in the specs that we have access to, I suspect blobs will always be returned in alphabetic order.  I'd be happy if someone from MS could verify this though.

Comment: Yes, it's alphabetical. I suspect that is documented somewhere, but not sure where...