# Azure Blob Index Tags search sort order

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

When doing a blob index tag search in C#:
_blobContainer.FindBlobsByTagsAsync(queryString);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=azure-portal

All matching blobs are returned, and they *seem* to be sorted on the blobname. However - to guarantee processing of all items when splitting up in separate invocations - is this guaranteed? Meaning: when you will get for instance 1.000.000 blobitems, are they sorted by blobname?

When listing blobs, it is validated that sort order is **guaranteed** (sorting of the blob path as a literal):
[Azure - Sort order of List operation on blob container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876519/azure-sort-order-of-list-operation-on-blob-container)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal).

Comment: The docs states:
Are there any requirements on index tag values?

Blob index tags only support string data types _and querying returns results with lexicographical ordering_. For numbers, zero pad the number. For dates and times, store as an ISO 8601 compliant format.

I _assume_ this means the ordering is guaranteed, but wish the docs would be more explicit